# $\operatorname{dist}(A, B) = 0 \land A \cap B = \emptyset \implies \partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A similar question: [Distance of two sets and their closest points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239534/distance-of-two-sets-and-their-closest-points)

The question above, however, defines distance differently.  The definition we work under is:

$$\operatorname{dist}(A, B)=\inf\{d(a,b):a \in A, b \in B\}$$

Informally, this must be true.  Imagine two open unit discs, $A$ and $B$, centered about $-1$ and $1$ respectively.  Notice that the distance $\operatorname{dist}(A, B) = 0$.  Even though $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $\partial{A} \cap \partial{B} = \{0, 0\} \neq \emptyset$.

I'm not really sure how to prove this formally, though.  Can anyone lend a hint?  Is there anything in the informal concept that can be used in proof?

---

$$\operatorname{dist}(A, B) = 0 \land A \cap B = \emptyset \stackrel{?}{\implies} \partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: The definitions are not equivalent. The one given here always makes sense, while the other one is not well-defined in some metric spaces. The infimum is not always attained, so is not a minimum in general. See the answer below and also the answers to the other question for some examples.

Comment: @Martin yeah sry you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False: Take $A=\mathbb Z^+$, the set of positive integers and $B=\{n+\frac1{2n}: n\in A\}$. Then $A=\partial A, B=\partial B, A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $d(A,B)=0$.

Comment: I hate confirmation bias.  This seems to work; a counterexample is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Another example: Let $A = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: xy = 1 \right\}$ and $B = \left\{(x,0): x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$. $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, closed, and as they have empty interior $\partial A = A$ and $\partial B = B$ while $d((n,0),(n, \frac{1}{n})) = \frac{1}{n}$ so $d(A,B) = 0$.

Comment: Hooray for $\mathbb{R}^2$!  +1 for easy visual :)

Comment: @vermiculus Believe or not, the first example that came to my mind was something very similar to Henno's answer: $A=\{xy=-1,x<0\}, B=\{xy=1,x>0\}$, but a "$1$-dimensional" example is more challenging, don't you think?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, agreed on that.  However, I'd still say that picturing an example (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) of where it *would* be true is far easier that picturing an example where it *wouldn't*, especially when the former has already come to mind.  

I only wish I could accept two answers...  (sigh)